# Error while using Json on Asp

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, post

I'm using JavaScript and C# on aspnet. And i want to pass 3 values from the Asp Page to the code behind, and to do so i am using Json method.
Here it is how i do:

```
   //initialize x, y and nome
   var requestParameter = { 'xx': x, 'yy': y, 'name': nome };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Canvas.aspx/GetData',
                data: requestParameter,
                //contentType: "plain/text",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.x);

                },
                error: function () { alert("error"); }
            });
```

And then on the C# i do:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData(Object[] output)
{
    return output.ToString();
}
```

For some reason i keep on getting the alert saying "error" (the one that i defined on the ajax post method). I would like to know why, and how can i avoid that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your web-method probably don't return valid JSON. Do `console.log(arguments)` instead of `alert("error")` and you'll see exact message in console. Most like it will be "Invalid character".

Comment: You need to check status code of response - use Fidder, Firebug or Chrome DevToolbar. If status is 404 - you can't access to method (maybe because of method marked as static). 
Otherwise update code to the following:
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
alert(textStatus);
alert(errorThrown);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change  `var requestParameter = { 'xx': x, 'yy': y, 'name': nome };` to

```
var requestParameter = { "xx": "'+x+'", "yy": "'+y+'", "name": "'+nome+'" };
```

also add

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

after  `[WebMethod]`

also before the declaration of class add

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

this tag is required to allow web methods to be called from scripts

Your webservice should be like this

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetData(String xx, String yy, String name)
{
    return xx+yy+name;
}
```

and jquery

```
 $.ajax({
url: '/Canvas.aspx/GetData',// the path should be correct
            data: '{ "xx": "'+x+'", "yy": "'+y+'", "name": "'+nome+'" }',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);

            },
            error: function (msg) {

                //alert(msg.d);
                alert('error');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help so far. I tried everything you said and i still get the same error. What could be missing?

Comment: I dont get it, still nothing... Am I missing some library or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The

```
 { 'xx': x, 'yy': y, 'name': nome }
```

Is not valid json.

A valid is

```
 var requestParameter = { "xx": 1, "yy": 11, "name": "test" }
```

In order to run just change the parameter on `webmethod` and from `object[]` to `Dictionary<string,object>`

As continue of your last comment i **update** my post with one more solution.

Aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
```

```
      function testmethod() 
          {
            var requestParameter = { "xx": 1, "yy": 11, "name": "adadsaasd111" };
            PageMethods.test(requestParameter);
           }

        function test() 
        {
            testmethod();
        }
    </script>

    <input id="Button1" type="button" onclick="return test();" value="button" />
</form>
```

cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void test(Dictionary<string,object> cal)
    {
       // todo 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is request params, jquery ajax method allows objects to be passed.

Comment: @Tommi You r saying that if you pass that object in a direct method it will play???

Comment: I say that jquery will serialize this object properly and write it to POST request body as valid json. I don't said anything about server-side.

Comment: Em, no, it's not, sorry. It serialize it as `xx=1&yy=2&name=nome`

Comment: Ok, i will change my post. You will have to do some changes.

Comment: @Chazz1 That's a simple example which runs ok.

Comment: Well thank you for you post anyway, hapned that my old code started to working and i dont know why, thanks guys for all you help tho :)